# "Розкриваюча" і "приймаюча" сторони в угоді про нерозголошення конфіденційної інформації

Tags: вживання-слів

В угодах про нерозголошення конфіденційності інформації є дві сторони:

1. Сторона 1, що надає конфіденційну інформацію.
2. Сторона 2, що отримує конфіденційну інформацію.

Дуже часто їх називають *розкриваюча сторона* та *приймаюча сторона*, що, на мій погляд, не є вірним з точки зору правил української мови.

Пошук в Google показує, що подібне написання є досить розповсюдженим явищем.

Які замінники можете порадити?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Сторона-розкривач* і *сторона-отримувач* (*сторона-одержувач*). Ці слова вже мають деякий вжиток:

> Крім цього, угодою мають бути обов’язково встановлені конструкції доступу для третіх осіб (наприклад співробітників компанії-одержувача або субпідрядників). На практиці вони різняться від письмового повідомлення *сторони-розкривача* про кожну особу, яка отримує доступ до інформації, до підписання окремих договорів про нерозголошення з ними.
> -- [Договір про нерозголошення конфіденційної інформації (NDA)](https://zkg.ua/dohovir-pro-nerozholoshennya-konfidentsijnoji-informatsiji-nda/)

Answer (score 1):

**У частині випадків** сторони можна назвати *замовник* і *виконавець*. Хоча стророна, що надає доступ до конфіденційної інформації, — не завжди замовник, а сторона, яка отримує доступ до конфіденційної інформації, — не завжди виконавець, але в частині випадків це так, тому іноді такі позначення доречно застосувати (особливо, якщо угода про нерозголошення є частиною пакета документів, і в решті документів пакети сторони називають так само).

(Також зазначу, що не кожна угода про нерозголошення має стророну, що надає доступ до конфіденційної інформації, і сторону, що отримує доступ до конфіденційної інформації, — угоди про нерозголошення також бувають [взаємні](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&oldid=30559335#%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8) і навіть [багатосторонні](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement#Multilateral).)